# Write multiple dataframes with a loop into SQL in R

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop, lapply

I have a list of dataframes. I want to use a loop to write them into my PostgreSQL database in R. However, I can only get the loop working on the first element of the list. Can anyone tell me how I can improve my loop?

`dcat` is a list of dataframes and `y2admin_2012`, `y2admin_2013`, `y2admin_2014` are dataframes.

```
dcat <- list(y2admin_2012, y2admin_2013, y2admin_2014)
```

I can write them one by one into my PostgreSQL.

```
dbWriteTable(con, "y2admin_2012", y2admin_2012)
dbWriteTable(con, "y2admin_2013", y2admin_2013)
dbWriteTable(con, "y2admin_2014", y2admin_2014)
```

But I am trying to write them in a loop but it failed in the naming element.

```
for (i in dcat) {
  dbWriteTable(con, "y2admin_"[i], i)
}
```

Comment: I think `dcat <- c(y2admin_2012, y2admin_2013, y2admin_2014)` should be `dcat <- list(y2admin_2012, y2admin_2013, y2admin_2014)`?? i.e. a list not atomic vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop over a vector of names as well. Does this work?

```
dcat <- list(y2admin_2012, y2admin_2013, y2admin_2014)
dcat_names <- c("y2admin_2012", "y2admin_2013", "y2admin_2014")

for(i in 1:length(dcat)){
  dbWriteTable(con, dcat_names[i], dcat[[i]])
}
```

Comment: Thanks @hammoire. It works. Also sorry for the typo earlier. It's a list, not a vector.

Comment: No problem, I do it all the time.